# Node.js : How to centralise npm modules ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I've got some troubles installing `node-canvas` with `npm` on Windows. It conducted me to do a lot of tests, changing some env variables, parameters, etc...

What's very annoying is that anywhere I am on my hard-drive, If I execute '`npm install -g canvas`' it will creates a folder '`node_modules`' locally... I didn't noticed that immediately so now I've got some 'node_modules' folders a bit everywhere (boring) -_-' ! I thought it was only in `users/user_name/appdata/roaming/npm` ?

I read that most people prefers to install node's dependency in the projet folder. it probably explains npm acts like this. How to avoid that ?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using local / project-specific modules? Whats the use case? For reference on npm's philosophy on global vs. local, see https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

Comment: because server-side node.js interest for some reasons but that I'm not planning to upload any projects for the moment, so I prefer to centralise my modules a bit like using pip in python. bad practice ? ok, I will read that

Comment: Using local node modules is de facto way of using npm. Unless you have a very good reason to use shared global modules, I would definitely avoid using them. Even some pip users feel like npm's approach is better: https://medium.com/@alonisser/things-i-wish-pip-learned-from-npm-f712fa26f5bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why people install node modules for the current working directory(project directory). The main reason being  If there is something that you are only going to use in your specific project then you want to install node modules locally. Also, this helps with using the correct version for your specific project. The only time you should be installing npm modules globally is if they are being used by other things outside your current project. 
A good example of this is nodemon, it watches the files in the directory in which nodemon was started, and if any files changed, it will automatically restart the application. So for this, you could install globally

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Of course, you can also just install it in your project directory

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```